# How to design analogue compensation for SMPS from Bode Plots?

Tags: power-supply, analog, control, bode-plot

In a complicated switched mode power supply where the transfer function is unknown, is there a way to design an analogue controller and compensation from the bode plot alone? I am having difficulty understanding how to calculate the poles and zeros of my system, and therefore difficulty in where to place the compensator poles and zeros.

I am able to use LTSpice to get the Bode plot of my system with a CLC pi-filter attached to reduce the voltage ripple on the output. I will attach this.

I gave no thought into the control loop as I was designing my power supply - the bode plot looks very strange to me and I have absolutely no clue how to interpret this to allow me to decide where to place the compensator poles and zeros to counteract the effects of the SMPS and ensure it is stable to transient load changes.

Furthermore, is there a way to decide whether I need a lag or a lead compensator?

Any help appreciated, thanks.

[image: System Bode Plot]

[image: Schematic]

[image: Control scheme]

[image: Buck Converter Step Response]

[image: LCC Step response]

[image: Series diode and secondary voltage]

Comment: Show your test setup schematically. I suspect this will indicate a few things that could simplify the bode plot.

Comment: @Andyaka Have now attached. Thanks.

Comment: Where is your input stimulus?

Comment: I was following an LTSpice tutorial online that told me to replace my input stimulus (270VDC) with instead an AC source with magnitude 1? Is this not correct?

Comment: Your diagram is really low in quality (try reading what you have posted) and I can't tell where your source is. Also, where is the feedback? I'm wondering why you don't ditch the whole switching part and inject your AC source right at the resonant inductor and then do a bode plot.

Comment: Andy, thanks for your reply. I think the quality is low in the post but when I click the link the quality is fine. Possibly try following this link, https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBdAv.png? At the moment my source is only a magnitude 1 AC source, but usually it is a 270VDC voltage. That's a good suggestion, I will try that. At the moment I have feedback resistors of 100Mohm and 46.5kOhm, 2.5V V_fb. I have not yet implemented the compensation.

Comment: Can you remove the background dot pattern and export it with higher resolution or make the text (values, designators) larger?

Comment: Embedded image and linked image are both poor. Ditto what winny says about those annoying dots.

Comment: Is the attached image any better? The only way I can export directly from LTSpice is to an .emf file, and I am unable to attach that here?

Comment: A bit. If everything else fails, try shrinking/compressing the schematic a bit and with the zoom all function, everything will be slightly larger.

Comment: @winny Okay, I think I've done that now and it seems to be much better, at least on my screen.

Comment: Oh! Buck regulated LLC with stacked rectifiers and 6 kV output! Looks like a fun project! How stable is the output from each stage, the buck and the LLC?

Comment: Yeah it's a very interesting project, I am really enjoying it. I am just having some teething issues with analogue control since I've never really implemented it before, just learnt about it. The transient analysis shows that at steady state the outputs are very steady - around 220VDC nominal from the buck, about 125V "clipped" sinusoid from the half bridge LCC (not LLC!) and then a very steady 6kV output with <100mV ripple voltage. I would like to be able to test the power supply stability with changes in load current/input voltage but can't without feedback (I think?)

Comment: Yes, about that. What is your feedback mechanism? Can you do a step response test for each stage and superimpose the results? How's voltage sharing on your secondary, both per winding and for your series diodes?

Comment: @winny I will attach what I have at the moment for feedback, I am using the LT1242 controller from Analog Devices in LTSpice. Obviously my compensation isn't yet calculated properly. I will also attach screenshots of the voltage on transformer secondaries (red, all are the same) and series diodes (green, blue).I will also attach the step response for the buck and the LCC, however I am unsure if I am doing this step right - I am just replacing the input source to PULSE(0 1 0 1u 1u 0.5m 5m)

Comment: @winny Did I do that right?

Comment: would be nice if you update your question...with some of the info in these comments @jvnlendm. It is also not clear how you generated the Bode plot? where do you insert the AC signal and where do you measure.

Comment: @jvnlendm Sorry about the delay. Swamped with work. Depends, what am I looking at in the graphs? We will need to start a chat here instead because I foresee plenty of discussion :-)

Answer (score 2):

1. You need to simplify your schematic, like using ideal switches instead of GaN devices, use ideal diodes instead of GaN diodes.
2. Don't consider Pi filter when you try to design the compensation parameters, the Pi filter will involve high frequency poles.
3. Run Bode plot to get transfer function without Pi filter, that means the feedback point should be located in front of Pi filter. so that it's better to remove Pi filter and after you get the correct compensation parameters and add it back.
4. Design the compensation parameter with Matlab or do calculation by yourself. there are many documents to show how to do compensation, like TI/ADI/Renesas application note. you can just search keyword with Google or ChatGPT.
5. Put your compensation parameters into your schematic, and use a step load to test the stability.
6. Use GaN devices instead of ideal switch, and add Pi filter back behind the feedback point.

Tips: LT1242 is a current mode controller that is pin to pin compatible with UC3842, you may need to learn about the external slope compensation for current mode.